# Contradiction to Helmholtz's Theorem 1: Vortex filaments have constant strength

Tags: vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz%27s_theorems

In fluid dynamics, according to Helmholtz's Thm 1, the strength of a vortex filament is constant along its length. 
A vortex filament is the streamline of the vector field curl(v), where v is the fluid velocity.

Let v=c(z)*[-y,x,0]. The vorticity w=curl(v)=[-x c'(z), y c'(z), 2 c(z)].
The vorticity has one streamline running vertically at x=y=0 with varying magnitude dependent on c(z). This seems to be a counterexample to Helmholtz's Thm 1.

Am I applying the Thm incorrectly somehow? or misinterpreting something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vortex filament is a vortex tube of infinitesimal cross-sectional area.  This is a structure that is aligned with the direction of vorticity and either the vorticity field vanishes or is parallel to the filament throughout a deleted neighborhood. In this case Helmholtz's first theorem applies in that the strength (the flux of vorticity through a disk perpendicular to the filament as the radius of the disk shrinks to zero) does not vary along the filament.

For example, imagine that we have a vortex filament aligned with the $z-$axis. Consider a tube with circular cross section of radius $R$ and length $Z$ enclosing the region

$$\Omega =\left\{x,y,z ) : \,\,0 \leqslant \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leqslant R, \,\,0 \leqslant z \leqslant Z \right\}$$

The boundary $\partial \Omega = S_0 \cup S_R \cup S_Z$ where $S_0$ and $S_Z$ are circular disks of radius $R$ located in the planes $z = 0$ and $z = Z$, respectively, and $S_R$ is the lateral surface

$$S_R = \left\{(x,y,z) : \,\, \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = R, \,\, 0 \leqslant z \leqslant Z \right\}$$

Since vorticity has zero divergence, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{\omega} = 0$, we have by the divergence theorem,

$$\tag{*} \int_{S_0} \mathbf{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS + \int_{S_Z} \mathbf{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS + \int_{S_R} \mathbf{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS = \oint_{\partial \Omega} \mathbf{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS = \int_{\Omega}\nabla \cdot \mathbf{\omega} \, dV = 0$$

With a vortex filament, we have either $\mathbf{\omega} = 0$ or $\mathbf{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{n} = 0$ on $S_R$.  This implies

$$-\int_{S_0} \mathbf{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS = \int_{S_Z} \mathbf{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS,$$

and since $\mathbf{n} = -\mathbf{e_z}$ on $S_0$ and  $\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{e_z}$ on $S_z$ we see that the strength of the filament does not depend upon $z$.

With your velocity field, the $z-$axis or any parallel line is not a vortex filament and there is no counterexample.

Note that the correct vorticity for this flow is $(\omega_x,\omega_y, \omega_z) = (-xc'(z), -yc'(z), 2c(z))$.  The integrals over the top and bottom surfaces, $S_0$ and $S_Z$, are

$$\int_{S_0} \mathbf{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS = - \int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \left.\omega_z\right|_{z = 0} R\, dr\, d\theta = -2\pi R^2c(0), \\ \int_{S_Z} \mathbf{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS =  \int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \left.\omega_z\right|_{z = Z} R\, dr\, d\theta = 2\pi R^2 c(Z),$$

and the lateral surface integral is

$$\begin{align}\int_{S_R} \mathbf{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^Z (\omega_x n_x + \omega_y n_y)\,R\, d\theta \, dz \\&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^Z c'(z)\left.\left( -x \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} - y\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right)\right|_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = R}\,R\, d\theta \, dz \\ &=  -\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^Z c'(z)  \,R^2\, d\theta \, dz \\ &= -2 \pi R^2 \int_0^Z c'(z) \, dz \\ &= -2\pi R^2 (c(Z) - c(0)) \end{align}.$$

If you ignore the contribution from the lateral surface integral, you erroneously conclude that

$$0 = \int_{S_0} \mathbf{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS + \int_{S_Z} \mathbf{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS  = 2\pi R^2 c(Z) - 2\pi R^2 c(0),$$

which implies that we must have $c(Z) = c(0)$ to ensure that the vortex tube strength is constant along its length, suggesting a  counterexample to Helmholtz's first theorem.

However, the contribution from the lateral surface integral always cancels the contributions from the ends so that (*) holds for any $Z$ and there is no contradiction when $c(z)$ is not constant.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm still confused about this though. Why do you say the z axis isn't a filament?  The direction of the vorticity on the z axis points along the z axis. Let's say c(z) is e^z. So the direction is always +z. This suggests to me that the z axis is a streamline of the vorticity.  I'm not sure what the relevance of boundary integrals is since the z axis runs through the interior. Also what's a deleted region? Thanks!

Comment: What you are calling a streamline of vorticity is a "vortex line" - a curve along which the tangent vector at every point is parallel to the local vorticity field at that point.  A bundle of vortex lines forms a vortex tube. The surface of a vortex tube is comprised of the vortex lines that pass through a given closed curve.  A vortex filament is just an idealized vortex  tube of infinitesimal cross section. On the lateral surface of the vortex tube, the vorticity has to be orthogonal to the normal vector.  It is true in your example, that the z-axis is a vortex line but not a filament.

Comment: The boundary integrals are relevant because how else do you prove the theorem other than the divergence theorem applied to a region surrounding the filament.

Comment: Unless you truly believe the Helmholtz theorem is wrong -- only discovered now -- then the problem is how you are visualizing a vortex filament.  Think of a curve where the vorticity field is concentrated on that line and with a direction tangential to the curve and where the vorticity vanishes an infinitesimal distance away from the curve.